# WPF - CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(XML) with XML as input

Tags: xml, wpf

I would like to filter a gridview based on the text in a textbox, this is the code i have:

```
public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var xElem = XElement.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\\Data\\Products.xml");

        this.defaultView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(xElem);
        this.defaultView.Filter = w => ((string)w).Contains(freeText.Text); // Null ref exception

        productGrid.ItemsSource = this.defaultView;

    }

    private void SearchProducts(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Filter GridView
        this.defaultView.Refresh();
    }
```

The above code is not working, i get a NullReference exception on line 7. My question is, is it possible to use XML directly like im doing in the above code? if so, how?

Comment: could you post the xml structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not get the default view for the root element but instead you can obtain for the child elements so modify as the example below

also you need to cast to XElement instead of string in order to specify the filter

```cs
    var xElem = XElement.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\\Data\\Products.xml");

    this.defaultView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(xElem.Elements("product"));
    this.defaultView.Filter = w => ((XElement)w).ToString().Contains(freeText.Text); 

    productGrid.ItemsSource = this.defaultView;
```

assuming the xml like below

```
<products>
    <product>...</product>
    ...
    <product>...</product>
</products>
```